# Solve this linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find particular solution of $\dfrac{dx}{dy} +x\cot y =y\cot y$ given $x=0$ when $y= π/2$.

Please help me figure this out 
I can't separate them out in order to integrate

Comment: Hint: integrating factors.

Comment: You can compute [integrating factor](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegratingFactor.html) and solve the differential equation.

Comment: There is no particular difficulty to solve this linear first order ODE thanks to usual methods. Edit your calculus up to the step where you are stuck so that we could help you.

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{dx}{dy} +x\cot y =y\cot y$$
Are you troubled by $\dfrac{dx}{dy}$ in the equation instead of $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ as usual ?

HINT :

Change the symbols : $\begin{cases} x=Y\\ y=X \end{cases}$
$$\dfrac{dY}{dX} +Y\cot(X) =X\cot(X)$$
Now this is a more usual form of linear first order ODE, easy to solve. I suppose that you can continue. At the end, come back to the original symbols.

Answer (score 1):

The DE

$$
x'(y) +x(y)\cot(y)=y \cot(y)
$$

is linear so it's solution can be written as

$$
x(y) = x_h(y) + x_p(y)
$$

with

$$
x_h'(y) +x_h(y)\cot(y)=0\\
x_p'(y) +x_p(y)\cot(y)=y \cot(y)
$$

The homogeneous is separable so we can easily obtain

$$
x_h(y) = C_0\csc(y)
$$

now making $x_p(y) = C(y)\csc(y)$ and substituting into the particular DE we have

$$
C'(y) = y\cos(y)
$$

and easily we obtain also

$$
C(y) = \cos(y)+y\sin(y)
$$

and finally

$$
x(y) = C_0\csc(y) + \left(\cos(y)+y\sin(y)\right)\csc(y)
$$
now using the initial conditions

$$
x\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=0\Rightarrow C_0 = -\frac{\pi}{2}
$$